# Is there a quick way to combine / merge these segments?

Tags: modeling

Is there an easy way of merging this entire selection so the faces on each side combine, or, would I have to select and merge each side individually?

[image]

Comment: select the central edge loop and dissolve it?

Comment: to expand.. first, Ctrl-V R remove doubles, if there are any, and then .. in edge mode, Alt-select the central loop, and X > Dissolve edges

Answer (score 1):

Temmy, I would select all the center vertices in vertex select mode with ALT-Click so that only the middle vertices are selected.  Then I would use LIMITED DISSOLVE to remove these vertices and that will combine the top, bottom, front, and rear faces into one face each.
Limited Dissolve can be chosen in 2.79 from the Mesh menu/Clean up/Limited Dissolve.